# element.length returns 0 even if the element exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below will dynamically create 5 table rows. I dont understand why `td.length` returns 0 even though I already created it. Can someone explains to me why?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $("#mytable");
        for(var c=1; c<6; c++){
            var id = "#row" + c;
            var tr = $("<tr><td id="+id+">Row "+c+"</td></tr>");
            table.append(tr);
        }
        var td = $("#row1");
        alert(td.length);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mytable">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id value itself should not contain the `#`.

Change this:

```
var id = "#row" + c;
```

to this:

```
var id = "row" + c;
```

The selector that you use with jQuery contains the `#`, but not the id value itself.